# Is it the case that each $\Phi^q$ of a stable cohomology operation $\{\Phi^q\}$ is a natural homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

So as the question statement asks, is it necessarily the case that each $\Phi^q$ of a stable cohomology operation $\{\Phi^q\}$ is a natural homomorphism? I suspect the answer is yes, but I don't know how to show it (I tried some failed attempts)...

Comment: Well, what does the definition of stable cohomology operation say?

Comment: I think you should tell us exactly what definition of stable coh. operation you are using and, ideally, where you get stuck in trying to prove this.

Comment: (Most definitions I have seen make the answer to this question trivially yes for cohomology operations for the naturality part and no for the homomorphism part, and yes and yes for stable cohomology operations. See May's Concise Course, end of chapter 22, for example)

Comment: I find it extremely strange that you would put a bounty on this question without ever replying to Mariano's comment... I highly doubt you will get an answer if you don't even tell us what you consider to be a stable cohomology operation!